# PHP echo resulting in jumbled up string

Tags: php, html

Basically I want to create a div with specific styling using PHP.

I have the following intended style saved up in a separate string for easy editing:

```
$bg = "background: url('./flags/" . $country[$id[0]]["iso"] . ".png')no-repeat center center fixed;";
```

And this is the `echo` that generates the div:

```
echo "<div class='flag' style='" . $bg . "'></div>";
```

When I run this code, the div does appear, but the style part is all jumbled up and weirdly formatted, like so:

```
<div class="flag" style="background:url(\" .="" flags="" hk.png\')no-repeat="" center="" fixed;'=""></div>
```

What is causing this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine for me! get different output! (Think you use other code as you show here, because you have a value inside the div tag!)

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes I was testing things and added that "sdf" thingy to see if it appeared, but it doesn't really interfere with anything else. I'll remove it to avoid confusion. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: http://ideone.com/1QQyQZ I don't get the same output with: `\"` or `.=""`

Comment: @Rizier123 Indeed that output seems to be correct. Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't have the style for .flag saved in a separate CSS file? That might avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: I think like @Nate and it's the best solution, but if you don't want a extra css file, i think you use other functions or code which modify's the output

Comment: @Nate I do in fact have the style for flag saved in my custom CSS, however I need to dynamically change the div's background image with PHP. There may be a better solution but right now I'm just curious as to why the echo appears all messed up.

Comment: Gotcha.  I think it might be related to the fact that in the $bg variable, you're encasing the url in single quotes -- but in your echo statement, you're doing the same thing for the style attribute.  So when your $bg variable renders, it's closing the single quotes.  I could be wrong, but I would try switching out the quotes in your $bg variable like this: $bg = 'background: url("./flags  ... etc ...

Comment: Your cod and source output don't match. Your code shows single quotes around tag properties and your source has double quotes. You are either not showing us your real code or not showing us your real source output.

Comment: @Nate Oh my god I just tested and that was it. Quite subtle. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll repost this here, since it worked out:

In the $bg variable, you're encasing the url in single quotes -- but in your echo statement, you're doing the same thing for the style attribute. So when your $bg variable renders, it's closing the single quotes. I could be wrong, but I would try switching out the quotes in your $bg variable like this:

```
$bg = 'background: url("./flags ... etc ...
```